# Inconsistent execution time for concurrent odbc2parquet requests

Tags: sql-server, odbc

### Issue

Concurrent executions of [odbc2parquet](https://github.com/pacman82/odbc2parquet) with no obvious difference take significantly different amount of time to be executed. In particular, the first operation to be started takes upwards of 10 times the average execution time (~1200+s, while the rest averages to less than 100s).

### Situation

I am using celery to distribute tasks to multiple workers (`concurrency` set to 30 as the processing can be storage-intensive) by cutting the data into sections.
The data in the SQL Server should be relatively uniform (no section should have significantly more data than others, certainly not 10 times the amount). The intuition that it doesn't come from the volume of data to be processed is reinforces by the fact that it always is the first operation that takes 10 times the time, with no relation to the section it processes.
Additionally, I am currently using the ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server.
For completeness, here is the command I use:

```bash
./odbc2parquet query 
    --connection-string "Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=<server_adress>;DATABASE=<database_name>;UID=<username>;PWD=<password>"
    <output_filename>.parquet
    "<SQL_request>"
```

### Question

Why is the first operation always this slow? Is it somehow related to the fact that it is the first connection to be done, before any other concurrent one?
How can this problem be solved?

If there are missing information for you to be able to properly assess the situation/answer the questions, please signal it to me. Thanks to everyone reading.

Comment: Have you used Performance Monitor to watch the instance's Disk IO? Possibly the first request has to load a large number of pages/extents off of a slow disk, whereas subsequent requests are answering the query from pages cached in memory?

Comment: From the metrics I can access, there is no real change when I execute my request or not. It seems the server already has a lot of things in memory (though I couldn't say what). Additionally, if I only start the processing for two sectors, whatever they are, the second is always fast. If this was the issue, then that would mean the first connection load data in memory and the second always happen to be in memory when the second connection is made. While it may be it, I find it unlikely. That said, if no connection linked issue could cause this, then it will be the favored explanation.

Comment: Hello, author of odbc2parquet here. First I am stating the obvious: `odbc2parquet` does not know whether it runs as the first of many processes. Could it be, that the first query triggers the creation of caches and/or indices in the database which later queries benefit from?

Comment: Maybe that is the case? The indices are already created, the cache on the other hand is almost certainly not. This is why I mentioned the "first" of many processes, as it would be the one triggering the creation of said cache. It is still surprising that the concurrent processes can finish before the end of the cache creation though. In any case, are you positive it would be more of a database configuration/running issue than a `odbc2parquet` issue?